# EmberJS: Unit testing a Component says common helpers like 'click' and 'andThen' are undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

### TLDR

I'm trying to unit test a very simple component. However, it appears some very common test helpers aren't being defined. This is something specific about unit-testing a component, as I'm using these in integration tests without issue.

Now just jump straight to the Questions at the end.

### Details

The errors are generic:

```
click is not defined
andThen is not defined
```

Stack trace for context:

```
Died on test #4     at Object.test (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:110:11)
at http://localhost:7357/assets/skylab.js:14977:15
at mod.state (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:150:29)
at tryFinally (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:30:14)
at requireModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:148:5)
at Object.TestLoader.require (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:29:9)
at Object.TestLoader.loadModules (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:21:18): click is not defined
```

The component and the tests are very basic. The component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.TextField.extend({
  classNames: ['input-span']
});
```

The Test:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import {
  moduleForComponent,
  test
} from 'ember-qunit';

moduleForComponent('custom-input');

test('focus on click', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(1);

  var component = this.subject();
  this.render();

  click('input')

  assert.ok(component.$('input').is(':focus'));
});
```

### Best Guess

My best guess is that these helpers work in the acceptance tests because the `startApp` helper creates the `click` and `andThen` helper functions. I don't have setup & teardown code in my `moduleForComponent` call, but it doesn't look like I should need it. And I don't want to test the whole app here -- just an isolated component.

### Questions

1. Is there another way to inject these test helpers that I'm unaware of?
2. Am I writing these tests wrong? Should I never use click in a component test? Is the documentation simply outdated?
3. Should this be supported as-written, and is this a framework bug I should report?

Comment: Try writing click('input') inside Ember.run()

Comment: @Vaibhav The good news is that I just tried that and it worked. The bad news is I just tried the code above unmodified and it also works. I have no idea what changed between yesterday and today, but now it seems to be working exactly as intended.

Comment: Found the difference. `Ember.run` doesn't matter. If I run all the tests, `click` is defined. If I just run the component tests (`ember test --server`, then selecting the `component:custom-input` module) then `click` is undefined.

Comment: Filed an issue with ember-cli: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3561

Answer (score 2):

acceptance level helpers currently depend on an app being spun up, as such they are not available for unit level tests. As those do not have an app.